# Servlet that starts a thread only once for every visitor

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, multi-user

Hey I want to implement a Java Servlet that starts a thread only once for every single user. Even on refresh it should not start again. My last approach brought me some trouble so no code^^. Any Suggestions for the layout of the servlet?

```
 public class LoaderServlet extends HttpServlet {
// The thread to load the needed information
private LoaderThread loader;
// The last.fm account
private String lfmaccount;

public LoaderServlet() {
    super();
    lfmaccount = "";
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (loader != null) {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(loader.getStatus());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } else {
        loader = new LoaderThread(lfmaccount);
        loader.start();
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/pages/loader.jsp").forward(
                request, response);
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (lfmaccount.isEmpty()) {
        lfmaccount = request.getSession().getAttribute("lfmUser")
                .toString();
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/pages/loader.jsp").forward(
            request, response);
}
}
```

The jsp uses ajax to regularly post to the servlet and get the status. The thread just runs like 3 minutes, crawling some last.fm data.

Comment: can you post the code that you tried so for?

Comment: What was your last approach ? Give some details/code snippets. Only then we can tell you how to improve upon it .

Comment: Why do you want to start a thread for every single user?  I would consider this approach not scalable as it means if you have 1000 users, then you'd need 1000 threads (each with their own stack, which may well play havoc with your memory).

Comment: If you told us the purpose more precisely maybe we could suggest a different, hopefully better approach to do what you want. The basic idea of locking threads to users seems very unusual to me in the Java EE world. It is usually better to let the container manage threads and avoid dealing with them.

Comment: So I have users that register on my site. After registrtation I have to crawl some lastfm data from their account. So no big task. What I want to avoid is them pressing refresh in their browser and by that fire new threads^^ and of course let multiple users crawl their stuff simultaniously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hypothetically it could be implemented by creating a `Map<String,Thread>` and then your servlet gets called it tries to look up the map with the `sessionId`.

Just a sketch:

```
public class LoaderServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private Map<String,Thread> threadMap = new HashMap<>();

  protected void doPost(..) {
    String sessionId = request.getSesion().getId();
    Thread u = null;
    if(threadMap.containsKey()) {
        u = threadMap.get(sessionId);
    } else {
       u = new Thread(...);
       threadMap.put(sessionId, u);
    }
    // use thread 'u' as you wish
  } 

}
```

Notes:

- this uses session id's, not users to associate threads
- have a look at `ThreadPools`, they are great
- as a commenter pointed out: **synchronization issues are not considered** in this sketch

Comment: There's a concurrency problem in this answer: what happens if there are 2 posts in the same session simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is [Session listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html). The method `sessionCreated()` will be called only once for every browser session. So, even if the user refreshes the page, there will be no issues.
You can then go ahead and start the thread for every `sessionCreated()` method call.

Answer (score 1):

Implement javax.servlet.SingleThreadModel => the service method will not be executed concurrently.
See the servlets specification.

Answer (score 0):

Your first task is to figure out how to identify users uniquely, for instance how would you discern different users behind a proxy/SOHO gateway?

Once you have that down it's basically just having a singleton object serving a user<->thread map to your servlet.

And then we get into the scalability issue as @beny23 mentions in a comment above... I absolutely concur with the point made - your approach is not sound scalability-wise!

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to **avoid parallel processing of requests from the same user**. I'd suggest you other approach: **associate lock with each user and store it in session**. And before start processing of users request - try to get that lock. So current thread will wait while other requests from this user are handling. (Use session listener to store lock, when session is created)